# Run-time error '3328' table is read-only

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

Hi i am working on access 2007-2013 application with DSN-less linked, the application is working perfectly, but when i shared it with other users i am getting the following error

> Run-time error '3328' table is read-only

i tried to enable the active x component in the application under options then go to trust center, and check [Never show information about blocked content]

also i noticed that when one user open the application the other user get this message

> Could not lock file

how can i solve this issue? i know i have to go to do something under options, but what?

thank you

Comment: It sounds like you are sharing the same copy of the FE (front end) with all users. Each user should have their own copy of the FE on their local machine (or profile if using remote desktop). For the reasons that you are experiencing, as well a s host of other reasons that you can easily bingoogle.

Comment: yes i will share the same copy with multiple user, then how can i do this in Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @AVG said, you're going to need split architecture.

This has to components:

### Back End

This is where all of your tables will be stored. It is just another Access database, without Forms/Queries/Reports/Modules.

### Front End

This is where you are going to Link to your Back End, and this *WILL* contain Forms/Queries/Reports/Modules, and create linked tables as well.

You're going to distribute this **Front End** to all of your users to solve these concurrency issues you're facing (people are editing records/viewing data and others are trying to write to that table and do other things at the same time, which Access doesn't like).

The **Back End** needs to be in a location where everyone has access to it.

I think in your question what you're asking for, would be [this](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/multi-user-application-record-locking.html), but splitting the front end and back end is by far the best route to go. Simply turning off the security checks Access has in place *to protect your data* isn't advised in the least. It also helps reduce bloat.

For disabling record locks : Click the top left Office Button, Click Options, Click Advances. Select `No Locks`.

Comment: i solved the issue by give the user write and read permission to the folder contains the application in Access DB

Comment: Well I hope that worked out for you.. Anything pop up?